# Problem with mouse cursor in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, mouse, awesome

My mouse pointer is changing to a **semi-transparent** box when it is in the dock. It is very annoying for me. Also the app icons has changed and there are no minimise and maximise buttons only the close button is there. Also when moved upon links it is changing to a hand pointing the link from side-wards.

*I was trying to set-up awesome window manager and at some point I think I did something wrong and everything changed to this state. Now I don't want that Awesome WM I just want my old settings back* .

Can anyone tell my how to change it back to my settings?